# Software Engineering Manager Roadmaps

Tags: management, planning, expectations

3.5 weeks into a new job & company as software engineering manager I was asked to create a road map for the year. they are new to doing agile/scrum. I still am learning the business/systems are.  Still learning what the developers are capable of.  For the 1st week I had to do company wide training.

Am I wrong in thinking this is unrealistic? Since the Product Owner and my manager didn’t complete it themselves for 3 months yet (before I was hired).

Trying to figure out what to do and how to do it, with out knowing the grind devs go through.

Comment: Hint: a roadmap is not a detailed schedule. Also, Agile has nothing to do with your task. Your task is a basic task for any project and for any project manager. You might not be suitable for the job as of now, or you might need extensive training in the field.

Comment: What, exactly, are they asking for? Are they looking for your personal roadmap for what you plan on doing over the next year? Or are they looking for a product roadmap? It seems reasonable to lay out a personal roadmap for the next few months, at least.

Comment: It is not a product roadmap necessarily.  We are a support software development team for internal people.  But in essence yes it is a projects' roadmaps.  No specific one product.  So we can get things thrown over they wall or they are trying to do projects where things are broken down into a spec and a plan is made for each spec.  They used to be water fall going to agile know resulting in wagile.

Comment: Do you have multiple Scrum teams? Since you used "Product Owner" (singular), wouldn't that be their job?. What *is* your job as a Software Engineering Manager supposed to be?

Answer (score 5):

> Am I wrong in thinking this is unrealistic?

You may be overthinking this.

Just put together your plans for the year at a high level. Accuracy likely isn't important here, just something to discuss.

It can always be revised as you learn more.

If you aren't clear what their expectations are regarding this road map, ask them.

Comment: You are probably right I might be thinking their expectations to be too high or expecting me to be accurate.  Prior I worked in a kaban system before where things where tossed over the wall and we worked on it as a engineering manager  for SAAS based companies.  I give them a estimation for the project they wanted to do and then a more accurate estimation when we got the spec and broke it down.  I wasn't involved in the yearly road map.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to other managers at your level, preferably others working for your manager, to find out what is actually being asked for, and at what level of detail. A "road map" can mean anything from a general set of goals for yourself to detailed goals for the department. If still not sure, ask your manager directly what kind of detail they are looking for.

Since you're being told to get together with the product groups, do that, find out and prioritize their needs, figure out the resources needed for each one and how that will be spread across your department, estimate time needed to solve each one (and which depend on others), allow for vacations and meetings and other interruptions, produce sketch of when each should be completed, submit that

You aren't expected to know all the details of your new company's processes and priorities immediately. The only way to learn is to ask.

Rule given to new pilots: "If lost, climb and confess."

(I take it you haven't held a managerial position before? As with any change in assignment, expect a learning curve.)

Comment: Roadmap is project based on the work for the other 3 quarters this year. Thanks for the answer. I have asked he shows me epics (I don't think is enough work for the year BTW) & says he wants dates for when they are completed. I get no other information about what else is in the works by product.  I ask product owner & he says he relies on my manager for this information and the prior manager I replaced used to provide it. This isn't a traditional software. It is a back end tools group that creates software supporting internal work. When I ask I get told get together w/product.

Comment: Response folded into Answer. Though I'd add that if you don't think you have enough work for the year that probably means you aren't being proactive enough. There is _always_ a backlog of things that need doing, from bugfixes to test development to documentation to new features. If there isn't already a task list system, putting one in place is probably a work item. ...

Answer (score 1):

You've been there for almost a month. Closer to half a month if you spent an entire week on just training, although I would expect that first week to have included getting to know your new team and getting somewhat acquainted with the team direction and goals.

By now you should be able to put down a skeleton of a plan for the next year. This would include broader team goals, milestones, and projects. No one should be expecting you to have a thorough knowledge of your developers capabilities and speeds, so this roadmap is more of a starting off point rather than a strict plan you have to follow.

Now your question is how unrealistic is this. That depends on how long they have given you to complete this and how in detail they expect it to be, but no I do not think this sounds unrealistic. Make sure you include any caveats you have, such as not being familiar with your devs' capabilities yet, so that you can point to those later on if someone *does* get upset about any inaccuracies.

Comment: I can deal with a starting off point as long as they realize there is no way I can put accurate dates on this with out knowing the tech involvement, how the dev work and how fast or slow they are.  Actually the 1st week had nothing to do with the Team knowing the goals or direction. I just found out one goal today, for last quarter.  It is something I upended because they were going in the wrong direction tech wise.  I been dealing with keeping things moving and knowing the current issues and trying to resolve them.  So not much on the roadmap/goals/directions.

Comment: They expect me and the new scrum master to put together a status on last quarters goal. and present it together.  Not the product owner but the SEM and Scrum Master. It is not a software company it is a bank and my group does backend internal processing and software creation to support internal workings.